# VB.Net retrieve data from USPS website

Tags: vb.net, usps

I am using the following HTML code in order to track packages with my USPS Web tools account

```
                http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=
```

```
               

               1

            xxx.xx.x.x

          xxx
```

the response is like the following

```
          <TrackResponse>

           <TrackInfo ID="XXXXXXXXXXXX">

           <Class>First-Class Package Service</Class>

          <ClassOfMailCode>FC</ClassOfMailCode>

         <DestinationCity>ERLANGER</DestinationCity>

        <DestinationState>KY</DestinationState>

       <DestinationZip>41025</DestinationZip>

      <EmailEnabled>false</EmailEnabled>

      <KahalaIndicator>false</KahalaIndicator>

       <MailTypeCode>DM</MailTypeCode>

        <MPDATE>2017-01-08 11:28:09.000000</MPDATE>

        <MPSUFFIX>748766316</MPSUFFIX>

      <OriginCity>INDIANAPOLIS</OriginCity>

      <OriginState>IN</OriginState>

      <OriginZip>46227</OriginZip>

        <PodEnabled>false</PodEnabled>

        <PredictedDeliveryDate>January 12, 2017</PredictedDeliveryDate>

         <RestoreEnabled>false</RestoreEnabled>

         <RramEnabled>false</RramEnabled>

          <RreEnabled>false</RreEnabled>

          <Service>USPS Tracking<SUP>&#174;</SUP></Service>


          <ServiceTypeCode>001</ServiceTypeCode>

           <Status>Delivered</Status>

            <StatusCategory>Delivered</StatusCategory>

           <StatusSummary>

           Your item was delivered at 4:07 am on January 12, 2017 in ERLANGER, KY 41025.

            </StatusSummary>

           <TABLECODE>T</TABLECODE>

           <TrackSummary>

          <EventTime>4:07 am</EventTime>

         <EventDate>January 12, 2017</EventDate>

          <Event>Delivered</Event>

          <EventCity>ERLANGER</EventCity>

          <EventState>KY</EventState>

          <EventZIPCode>41025</EventZIPCode>

          <EventCountry/>

          <FirmName/>

          <Name/>

          <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

         <EventCode>01</EventCode>

         </TrackSummary>

          <TrackDetail>

         <EventTime>3:31 am</EventTime>

        <EventDate>January 12, 2017</EventDate>

        <Event>Departed USPS Facility</Event>

         <EventCity>CINCINNATI</EventCity>

         <EventState>OH</EventState>

        <EventZIPCode>45234</EventZIPCode>

         <EventCountry/>

         <FirmName/>

          <Name/>

       <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

        <EventCode>10</EventCode>

        </TrackDetail>

        <TrackDetail>

        <EventTime>3:28 am</EventTime>

        <EventDate>January 12, 2017</EventDate>

        <Event>Arrived at Post Office</Event>

         <EventCity>CINCINNATI</EventCity>

       <EventState>OH</EventState>

      <EventZIPCode>45234</EventZIPCode>

       <EventCountry/>

       <FirmName/>

       <Name/>

       <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

         <EventCode>07</EventCode>

        </TrackDetail>

        <TrackDetail>

        <EventTime>8:41 pm</EventTime>

        <EventDate>January 11, 2017</EventDate>

        <Event>Arrived at USPS Facility</Event>

        <EventCity>CINCINNATI</EventCity>

        <EventState>OH</EventState>

        <EventZIPCode>45234</EventZIPCode>

        <EventCountry/>

       <FirmName/>

        <Name/>

        <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

       <EventCode>10</EventCode>

       </TrackDetail>

       <TrackDetail>

       <EventTime>2:34 am</EventTime>

        <EventDate>January 11, 2017</EventDate>

       <Event>In Transit to Destination</Event>

       <EventCity/>

        <EventState/>

      <EventZIPCode/>

        <EventCountry/>

         <FirmName/>

           <Name/>

           <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

          <EventCode>EX</EventCode>

         </TrackDetail>

        <TrackDetail>

        <EventTime>2:34 am</EventTime>

       <EventDate>January 10, 2017</EventDate>

       <Event>Arrived at USPS Origin Facility</Event>

       <EventCity>INDIANAPOLIS</EventCity>

      <EventState>IN</EventState>

    <EventZIPCode>46241</EventZIPCode>

    <EventCountry/>

   <FirmName/>

     <Name/>

    <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

    <EventCode>10</EventCode>

    </TrackDetail>

    <TrackDetail>

    <EventTime>1:22 pm</EventTime>

    <EventDate>January 9, 2017</EventDate>

    <Event>Picked Up</Event>

    <EventCity>INDIANAPOLIS</EventCity>

    <EventState>IN</EventState>

    <EventZIPCode>46227</EventZIPCode>

   <EventCountry/>

   <FirmName/>

    <Name/>

    <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

    <EventCode>03</EventCode>

    </TrackDetail>

    <TrackDetail>

    <EventTime>4:43 pm</EventTime>

   <EventDate>January 8, 2017</EventDate>

   <Event>Shipping Label Created, USPS Awaiting Item</Event>

   <EventCity>INDIANAPOLIS</EventCity>

   <EventState>IN</EventState>

   <EventZIPCode>46227</EventZIPCode>

   <EventCountry/>

   <FirmName/>

   <Name/>

    <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

    <EventCode>GX</EventCode>

    <DeliveryAttributeCode>33</DeliveryAttributeCode>

    </TrackDetail>

    <TrackDetail>

    <EventTime/>

    <EventDate>January 8, 2017</EventDate>

    <Event>Pre-Shipment Info Sent to USPS, USPS Awaiting Item</Event>

    <EventCity/>

    <EventState/>

    <EventZIPCode/>

    <EventCountry/>

    <FirmName/>

    <Name/>

    <AuthorizedAgent>false</AuthorizedAgent>

    <EventCode>MA</EventCode>
    </TrackDetail>

    </TrackInfo>

    </TrackResponse>
```

How can i retrive some of the information between the HTML tags and put it into a textbox? i cannot find any Element ID so i cannot use the GetElementbyid
please help
thank you

Comment: Probably because the post office API pass back XML not HTML https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/general-api-developer-guide.htm#_Toc423593922

Comment: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/smunk/using-usps-web-tools-with-vbnet-or-c-34277

Answer (score 0):

You could use XmlDocument, something like this:

```
Dim currXml As New XmlDocument
currXml.Load(responseStream)
Dim idXml As XmlNodeList = currXml.GetElementsByTagName("TrackInfo ID")
Dim id As String = idXml(0).InnerText`
```